# iOS how to call presentViewController upon already stacked ViewController

Tags: ios, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am trying to push a view controller upon an already pushed view controller like below. However, somehow when I tried to push the `newPersonViewController`, this new controller doesn't get pushed onto the stack. I do not know why Xcode is complaining that I am trying to add a new controller that doesn't belong to the hierarchy. Did I present the `ABPeoplePickerViewController` incorrectly? Is this the reason why the `newPersonViewController` couldn't get pushed onto the stack?

Message from console:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

The code:

```
- (void)addPerson
{
    ABNewPersonViewController *newPersonVC = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
    newPersonVC.newPersonViewDelegate = self;
    UINavigationController *uiNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newPersonVC];

    [self presentViewController:uiNav animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)showPeoplePicker
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    [picker.topViewController setEditing:YES];
    picker.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addPerson)];
    picker.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(peoplePickerCancel)];
}
```

Comment: The root of the problem was the presence of the `[self presentViewController:...]` in `addPerson` because `self` is not the current view controller. Just change that to be the new property and you're done! Sorry to torture you with edits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `addPerson` is trying to present modally from the view controller that's not the current controller. The `self` (your original view controller) is not the active controller. The `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` is.

So, first, define a class property to keep track of the `picker`:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker;
```

And then,

- Modify `showPeoplePicker` to set that property; and
- Modify `addPerson` to use that property:

Thus:

```
- (void)addPerson
{
    ABNewPersonViewController *newPersonVC = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
    newPersonVC.newPersonViewDelegate = self;
    UINavigationController *uiNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newPersonVC];

    [self.picker presentViewController:uiNav animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)showPeoplePicker
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    [picker.topViewController setEditing:YES];
    picker.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd    target:self action:@selector(addPerson)];
    picker.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(peoplePickerCancel)];

    self.picker = picker;
}

- (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonView didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    [newPersonView dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob, Thank you so much! It's working now. I was thinking about picking the wrong active view controller as well, but had no idea about how to fix it. earlier I tried:
`[self.presentingViewController presentViewController:uiNav animated:YES completion:nil];`
and
`[self.presentingViewController.navigationViewController presentViewController:uiNav animated:YES completion:nil];`
as well, but it was not working. So, I thought that calling `self.presentingViewController` would give me the currently displaying view controller.